# How to use .css() method with array?

Tags: jquery

I need to apply style to all elements of class.

```js
const history_cells = $(".history-cell");

for (var i = 0; i < history_cells.length; i++) {
    history_cells[i].css({"opacity": "1"});
}
```

But have

> Uncaught TypeError: history_cells[i].css is not a function.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery handles collections of elements just as it would with a single element, so going

```
$(".history-cell").css({"opacity": "1"})
```

does the job.

On the other hand, I strongly recommend not to use inline styles. Rather do this:

```
$(".history-cell").addClass('opaque');
```

and add this class in your CSS:

```
.opaque { opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a foreach loop syntax in jquery better than for loop

```js
$(".a").each(function(i,e) {
   $(this).html(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="a"></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: No need for an explicit loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the error in this simple way

```
$(history_cells[i]).css({"opacity": "1"});
```

However, you can also do it like below instead

```
$(".history-cell").css({"opacity": "1"});
```

Comment: No need for an explicit loop.

Comment: Yes @connexo . I've updated my answer with 2 solutions **`get rid of the error` and `the simple way to resolve`**

Answer (score 1):

Change little

```
const history_cells = $(".history-cell");

for (var i = 0; i < history_cells.length; i++) {
    $(history_cells[i]).css({"opacity": "1"});
}
```

Comment: $() is helps you to pick up your content and add css or class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class using jquery 2 types.
First you can create CSS class then apply it.

```
$('your input').addClass('class Name');
```

For Ex:

```
$('.history-cell').addClass('opacity');
```

Second You can apply it directly using following:

```
$('your input').css({"your need(backgroundcolor, font or etc)":"value(color,size px or %)"});
```

For Ex:

```
$('.history-cell').css({"opacity": "1"});
```

Apply style using loop:

```
$(".history-cell").each(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    //Or use direct class is better
    $(this).addClass('opacity');   
});
```